# Counting unique dates between two dates in Excel

Tags: excel

I am stuck with the issue to calculate number of unique dates between two dates. My sample table looks like this:

```
Column A     Column B     Column C     Column D 
10/1/2015
1/8/2016
2/25/2016                 2/1/2016     3/15/2016 
2/25/2016
2/25/2016
3/4/2016
3/24/2016
```

C3:D3 hold from and to dates respectively.

And this is my formula I am trying to get to work:

=SUMPRODUCT(--(FREQUENCY(IF(A1:A7>=C3+0,A1:A7,0),IF(A1:A7<=D3+0,A1:A7,0))>0))

It gives me some number, but the numbers are not correct. For this particular example I get 1 when 2 is expected. Any ideas what is wrong here?

Comment: Can you reword the question? I am a little confused by what you mean by "unique dates between two dates." Is this looking for how many unique dates you have in the list or how many dates you have in between the two dates you specified?

Comment: Sorry for misleading description. My question is how many unique dates are in A1:A7 that are in the range between the dates, specified in C3 and D3. In this example I expect that formula give me number 2, because there are only 2 unique dates between Feb-01 and Mar-15 2016.

Comment: You need to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter instead of Enter it is an array formula

Comment: Is it really? Well, I get 4 when I enter it as an array formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
=SUM(N(FREQUENCY(IF((myRange>=C3)*(myRange<=D3),myRange,""),IF((myRange>=C3)*(myRange<=D3),myRange,""))>0))
```

entered as an array formula by holding down <kbd>ctrl+shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>